# Non-unitarity of finite dimensional Lorentz group and its implications

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, unitarity

In Peskin and Schroeder, section 3.2, it is stated that Lorentz group being non-compact it does not have any finite dimensional, faithful unitary representation. But it has also been said that one shouldn't worry because $\psi$ is not a wavefunction but a field.

Now my question is, (editing as per recommendation by Qmechanic to ask the subquestions in separate posts)

Why do we not have to worry about non-unitarity in the case of a field?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358390/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic More like a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99051/