# Are the generators of the $SU(2)_L\times SU(2)_R$ group unitary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, unitarity

In the chiral model, the quark field $q=\begin{pmatrix} u \\ d \end {pmatrix}$ transforms like $q\rightarrow\exp({i(\theta_a\tau^a+\gamma_5\beta_a\tau^a)})\;q$. Now, I understand that the transformations defined by
$$
U = {i(\theta_a\tau^a+\gamma_5\beta_a\tau^a)}
$$
are the generators of the $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ chiral group. Now, to couple the electromagnetic fields for instance, one introduces gauge fields $A_\mu$ that transform like
$$
A_\mu \rightarrow U A_\mu U^\dagger - \frac{i}{g}(\partial_\mu U)U^\dagger
$$
which allows the definition of a covariant derivative so that the derivatives transform like the fields (this is the usual method also used to couple scalar fields to QED).

These transformations imposed on $A_\mu$ only work to produce the desired outcome if $U^\dagger U = 1$.

However, as explained in Schwartz's Quantum Field Theory, this property can not be true for generators of the Lorentz group, since there are not finite-dimensional spinor representations of the Lorentz group that are unitary.

How does one reconcile these two facts? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The group of your title commutes with the Lorentz group.  Its representations are unitary under it.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358390/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99051/2451 and links therein.

Comment: you're confusing *group* elements with *algebra* elements. The $U$ in your first equation is an algebra element, the $U$ in your second equation is a group element, they denote different objects and you should use different symbols. (The two $U$'s are not independent though: they satisfy $U_{2\text{nd}}=\exp(U_{1\text{st}})$). Group elements are unitary, algebra elements are hermitian.,