# Matrix representation of Lorentz boost acting on a scalar

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, representation-theory, matrix-elements

For the unitary translation operator $\hat{X}_a$ in 1 dimension it is easy to show that its matrix elements can be expressed purely with a delta distribution or equivalently as a combination of a differntial operator with a delta distribution.

Definition of its matrix elements: $\int \mathrm{d}x' X_a(x,x') \psi(x') = \psi(x-a)$

With delta distibution: $X_a(x,x') = \delta(x'-(x-a))$

Mixed with differential operator: $X_a(x,x') = \mathrm{e}^{-a\partial_x}\delta(x'-x)$

$\psi(x-a) = \int \mathrm{d}x'\delta(x'-(x-a))\psi(x') 
= c\int \mathrm{d}x'\mathrm{d}k\ e^{\mathrm{i}kx'}e^{-\mathrm{i}kx}e^{\mathrm{i}ka}\psi(x')
= c\int \mathrm{d}x'\mathrm{d}k\ e^{\mathrm{i}kx'}e^{-a\partial_x}e^{-\mathrm{i}kx}\psi(x')
= ce^{-a\partial_x}\int \mathrm{d}x'\mathrm{d}k\ e^{\mathrm{i}k(x'-x)}\psi(x')
= e^{-a\partial_x}\int \mathrm{d}x' \delta(x'-x)\psi(x')\quad q.e.d.$

---

Now I want to have the same scheme for a Lorentz boost $\hat{\Lambda}$. I want to have the scalar product defined as integral over $x$ and $t$. (I just want to have it this way, so please don't start a discussion that in QFT the scalar product is defined differently.)

Definition of its matrix elements: $\int \mathrm{d}t'\mathrm{d}x' \Lambda(t,t',x,x') \psi(t',x') = \psi(\gamma t - \gamma\beta x, \gamma x - \gamma\beta t)$

With delta distibution: $\Lambda(t,t',x,x') = \delta(t'-(\gamma t - \gamma\beta x))\cdot\delta(x'-(\gamma x - \gamma\beta t))$

Mixed with differential operator: $\Lambda(t,t',x,x') =\ \textbf{???}$

---

And here I'm stuck. I found this [Infinite-dimensional representation of Lorentz algebra](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/678367/infinite-dimensional-representation-of-lorentz-algebra) for an infinitesimal boost on a scalar. So I started with $x\partial_t + t\partial_x$ and the  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula .

Set $X=x\partial_t$ and $Y=t\partial_x$. Then it follows

$[X,Y]=x\partial_x - t\partial_t$

$[X,[X,Y]]=-2X$ and $[Y,[Y,X]]=-2Y$

With the help of these it follows

$[Y,[X,[X,Y]]]=2[X,Y]$ and $[Y,[Y,[Y,X]]]=0$

Furthermore

$[[[[Y,X],Y],X],Y]=4Y$ and $[[[[X,Y],X],Y],X]=4X$

So the first terms of $Z(X,Y)$ sum up to

$Z(X,Y) = \left(1-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{30}+... \right)(X+Y) + \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12}+... \right)[X,Y]$

and I expect a lot of work. Therefore the question: is there any ready-to-use formula for the $\textbf{???}$ above?

---

**Update**

The proposal of Thomas with $\beta=\tanh\zeta$, $\gamma=\cosh\zeta$,  $\gamma\beta=\sinh\zeta$ gives us when Fourier transforming the delta distributions:

$\Lambda(t,t',x,x') = c^2 \int \mathrm{d}\omega\mathrm{d}k\ e^{\mathrm{i}\omega t'} e^{\mathrm{i}k x'} e^{-\zeta\ (x\partial t + t \partial x)} e^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t} e^{-\mathrm{i}k x}$

On the other hand the variant with the product of two $\delta$s gives us:

$\Lambda(t,t',x,x') = c^2 \int \mathrm{d}\omega\mathrm{d}k\ e^{\mathrm{i}\omega t'} e^{\mathrm{i}k x'} e^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t\cosh\zeta}e^{-\mathrm{i}k x\cosh\zeta}e^{\mathrm{i}k t\sinh\zeta}e^{\mathrm{i}\omega x\sinh\zeta} $

I guess if both shall be true we must show that

$e^{-\zeta\ (x\partial t + t \partial x)} e^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t} e^{-\mathrm{i}k x} = e^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t\cosh\zeta}e^{-\mathrm{i}k x\cosh\zeta}e^{\mathrm{i}k t\sinh\zeta}e^{\mathrm{i}\omega x\sinh\zeta}$

and the very left $e$ function will expand to a very ugly term according to the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula where convergence might become a problem. Maybe the assumption (both forms of the matrix elements are equivalent) is wrong. But then I'd like to know why. Or the assumption is correct, then one should find a proof of the equivalence somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but... I never found the "With delta distribution" form anywhere. Maybe it is wrong. But why then? Or if it is true, the proof of equivalence to the form proposed by Thomas appears to me not quite easy. See Update section.

Comment: [Truax](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.31.1988).

Comment: Have you solved the analog rotation problem, where [everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform) is known explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

Motivated from [Lorentz transformation (Coordinate
transformation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Coordinate_transformation) my guess would be
$$\Lambda(t,t',x,x') = e^{-\zeta(x\partial_t+t\partial_x)}\delta(t'-t)\delta(x'-x)$$
where $\zeta$ is the rapidity, defined by $\tanh\zeta=\beta$.
<s>But I cannot give a proof for it.</s>

Instead of proving
$$\delta(t'-(\gamma t-\gamma\beta x))\delta(x'-(\gamma x-\gamma\beta t))
= e^{-\zeta(x\partial_t+t\partial_x)} \delta(t'-t)\delta(x'-x) \tag{1}$$

it is actually easier to prove the more  general
$$\psi(\gamma t-\gamma\beta x,\gamma x-\gamma\beta t)
= e^{-\zeta(x\partial_t+t\partial_x)}\psi(t,x) \tag{2}$$
for arbitrary functions $\psi$.
Then (1) will follow from (2) as the special case $\psi(t,x)=\delta(t'-t)\delta(x'-x)$.

Let us first consider the arguments of $\psi$ on the left side of (2)
and rewrite them.
$$\begin{align}
 \begin{pmatrix} \gamma t-\gamma\beta x \\ \gamma x-\gamma\beta t \end{pmatrix}
&=\begin{pmatrix} \gamma & -\gamma\beta \\ -\gamma\beta & \gamma \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}t \\ x \end{pmatrix}  \\
&=\begin{pmatrix} \cosh\zeta & -\sinh\zeta \\ -\sinh\zeta & \cosh\zeta \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}t \\ x \end{pmatrix} \\
&=\exp\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\zeta \\ -\zeta & 0 \end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix} t \\ x \end{pmatrix} \\
&\underset{n\to\infty}{=}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -\zeta/n \\ -\zeta/n & 1 \end{pmatrix}^n
 \begin{pmatrix} t \\ x \end{pmatrix} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

That means we get the left side of (2) by applying the infinitesimal transformation
$$\psi(t,x) \mapsto \psi\left(t-\frac{\zeta}{n}x,x-\frac{\zeta}{n}t\right)  \tag{4}$$
$n$ times, and letting $n\to\infty$.
Now, for large $n$ and neglecting terms $O(1/n^2)$, transformation
(4) is (by the definition of partial derivatives) equal to
the transformation
$$\psi(t,x) \mapsto \left(1-\frac{\zeta}{n}x\partial_t-\frac{\zeta}{n}t\partial_x\right) \psi(t,x)  \tag{5}$$

Doing transformation (5) $n$ times we get
$$\begin{align}
\psi(t,x)
 &\mapsto \left(1-\frac{\zeta}{n}x\partial_t-\frac{\zeta}{n}t\partial_x\right)^n  \psi(t,x) \\
 &\underset{n\to\infty}{=} e^{-\zeta(x\partial_t+t\partial_x)}\psi(t,x) \tag{6}
\end{align}$$
So we finally got the right side of (2), q.e.d.

Disclaimer: Some steps above likely miss the mathematical rigor.
But for a physicist (like me) it is good enough.

Comment: This looks reasonable. I added an Update section to my question where you can see that a proof of equivalence to the other form means much work.

Comment: @HaraldRieder I have added a proof (elaborating the ideas from Cosmas Zachos' answer).

Comment: Thank you, Thomas! $\psi(t,x)=\delta(t'-t)\delta(x'-x)$ yes of course, then it becomes easy. So it just was a stupid idea trying it via Fourier transformations.

Answer (score 2):

I might expedite/explain the sound answer of @Thomas Fritsch, which the comment format makes all but impossible. With due apologies to the OP, an integral kernel (propagator) which is a delta function is pointless.

One  *supplants* it by vector field propagation as analyzed in the linked answer of mine,
$$
\psi(t,x)\mapsto  \psi(\cosh \zeta ~~t -\sinh \zeta ~~x, \cosh \zeta  ~~x  -\sinh \zeta ~~t)\\ =e^{-\zeta (x\partial_t + t\partial_x)} \psi(t,x). 
$$
The exponential is then merely the standard infinite repetition limit of the infinitesimal boost (commuting with itself),
$$
e^{-\zeta (x\partial_t + t\partial_x)}= \lim_{n\to \infty}  \left (1-\frac{\zeta}{n} (x\partial_t + t\partial_x) \right )^n .$$

Now, if you wish to replace your arbitrary test scalar by an integral of a delta function, that's an option, mysterious as it might appear to an outsider... The connection of rotations to shifts is always tortured, and I don't fully grasp the implicit motivation here.

Comment: Motivation? Here it comes. Short story: I once learned that abstract operators $\hat(O)$ will get matrix elements when a basis is chosen. I was wondering why you everywhere find $-\zeta (x\partial_t + t\partial_x)$ but nowhere a matrix (here: a function of multiple variables).

Comment: Long story: the "with delta distribution" matrix representation can conveniently be applied to a given function $\psi(t,x)$. Thereby entanglement between t- and x- spaces gets changed. And this I need for an idea that observers observe changes of entanglement between t- and x-space. The whole story is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QBa3pBlB3BKuZXR7mlOHTG96iTsc2-RV/view?usp=drive_link