# What is the difference between $UXU^{-1}$ and $UX$?

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a state $X$ living in some vector space $S$ and a linear operator $U$ that acts on $S$. Now, my understanding is that if $X$ and $U$ are expressed in the same representation, say both are $n\times n$ matrices, then the action of $U$ on $X$ is given by $UXU^{-1}$. But if $X$ is some spinor and $U$ is a matrix, then the action is given by $UX$. Can you confirm this? And possibly also give me more details on what the exact mathematical difference between the two is and how that difference can be explained. Thanks.

Edit: So, I was asked to give context. This question came up specifically within the context of Lorentz transformations acting on a (left-handed) spinor but it was asked more generally since I have come across this point of confusion many times before. Here are the specifics:

Suppose $U(\Lambda)$ is the Lorentz transformation acting in some spinor space $S$ where the spinor representation of some fermion $\chi$ also lives. If someone were to ask me how $\chi$ transforms under Lorentz transformations, I would have said $\chi\rightarrow U(\Lambda)\chi$. But what if the state $\chi$ was also represented as a matrix? Then I suppose the action of operators would change.

Comment: Can you give some context?

Comment: I assume that $S$ is a vector space and $U:S\rightarrow S$ is a linear map on $S$. In that case, $X$ is a vector and $U$ a matrix.

In this scenario, the action on vectors (states) are $UX$ but the action on operators $O:S\rightarrow S$ is $UO U^{-1}$. But it's easier to explain given the context.

Comment: So how is $XU^{-1}$ defined?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Although I originally thought to ask this question a bit more generally, I now realize adding specifics would have made it clearer. I have added some context.

Comment: I still don't understand. If $S$ is a vector space, then $x\in S$ is a vector and not a matrix (i.e. not a linear map on $S$). So why do you ask: *But what if the state $\chi$ was also represented as a matrix?*

Comment: This is exactly why I didn't want to give any context because the question is for some general mathematical object $X$ living in some space $S$. I can write $X$ in vector representation or matrix representation, for example in the case of a $(1/2,1/2)$ spinor. What I am asking is, for which type of object $X$ is the transformation under a linear operator $U$ given by $UXU^{-1}$ and for which by $UX$.

Comment: ACuriousMind’s answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174898/lorentz-algebra-representation-and-qft) should help clarify the situation.

Comment: @Ghoster Why do you think so? OP does not make a clear statement what $X$ is supposed to mean (either an element of a given vector space or a linear map on it, somehow confusingly without any motivation), so the question can mean anything.

Comment: @Hrach Unless you are trying to refer to the equivalence of a vector space of $N\times N$-matrices and $N^2$-component column vectors your question does not make sense. You can't just ask "what if states were also represented by matrices" without giving some kind of reasonably precise construction about how you plan to do this. It's like saying "now consider what would happen if the states were complex numbers", you need to tell us what that means before you ask for the consequences of making such a definition. As it stands, your question is not well-posed IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about *the* action of $U$ on $X$, but there are generally many possible actions of a group on itself. These are simply different actions - which one is 'the right one' depends on the circumstances. It's not to do with the type of object you are applying it to, it's about what sort of operation you want to apply. (Like, sometimes you *add* Real numbers together and sometimes you *multiply* them. Which is correct?)

Using elements of a group to represent a state is a fairly common manoeuvre. You pick a specific but arbitrary state from the state space to serve as an "origin", and then you apply transformations to it that result in the state being referred to. So Cartesian coordinates can be described as picking an origin point, and then applying successive translations in $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions to reach the point being referred to. Latitude and longitude coordinates on the Earth are implemented by picking an origin point off the coast of Africa, then applying a rotation through the angle of latitude about one axis, then a rotation through the angle of longitude about the polar axis. We are using the transformation to provide *coordinates* for the state space, but the transformation is not generally the state itself. Sometimes we can ignore the distinction, and sometimes it leads to deep confusion. This is especially true of linear transformations on a vector space, because the transformations themselves constitute a *different* vector space, which we sometimes use. Real $2 \times 2$ matrices act on a vector space of dimension $2$, but are themselves a vector space of dimension $4$. (The four elements of a $2 \times 2$ matrix can be varied independently.) Even if we restrict the group so the dimensions match (e.g. by just picking unitary or orthogonal matrices), the topology might still be different (e.g. if you use rotations). With spinors, a rotation of angle $\theta$ in one vector space is a rotation of angle $2\theta$ in the other. Be careful.

The two different actions above can arise in numerous ways. One way is via a mapping of mappings.

[image: Mappings square]

In the diagram, we have a mapping $X$ on the left from grey to green. We map both the start point and the end point using a different mapping $U$, to blue and red respectively. Then there are two mappings that we can describe as the combination of $X$ and $U$. There is the mapping across the diagonal, grey to red, from the *original* start point to the *mapped* destination point, which is $UX$. And we have the mapping down the right side of the diagram, blue to red, from the *mapped* start point to the *mapped* end point, which is $UXU^{-1}$. This goes round the other three sides, from blue to grey to green to red.

So if we are using $X$ to represent a state by means of its transformation from a fixed "origin" state, then with this interpretation the question is whether we are transforming the *state*, and the result is a new state relative to the same origin, or whether we are transforming the *transformation* and the origin doesn't matter. There may be other situations where it arises, and other interpretations. But the basic question is whether you are transforming both input and output of the transformation $X$, or only the output.

The $UXU^{-1}$ operation is called *conjugation* in group theory, and splits the group into *conjugacy classes*. It is an *inner automorphism* of the group, meaning it retains the group structure entirely. This gives it lots of useful properties, with many applications.